# comparative correlative with 3 parts

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, comparatives

Is it possible to construct a comparative correlative sentence with 3 parts?

e.g.,

> The more he walks, the less energy he has, the more tired he gets.

or must it be split into 2 parts, e.g.,

> The more he walks and the less energy remains, the more tired he gets

or

> The more he walks, the less energy he has and the more tired he gets

(or maybe there is a different way to put this?)

Comment: [**The** further and deeper the listener goes into ***The** Smoker You Drink, **The** Player You Get*, **the** more the notion of restlessness...](http://www.liverpoolsoundandvision.co.uk/2013/06/18/joe-walsh-the-smoker-you-drink-the-player-you-get-40th-anniversary-retrospective/) But I don't think you can chain more than two comparatives in this construction unless you're cheating by including text that forms part of a title/name.

Comment: Just add an 'and'.

Comment: I like the 'and' too.  I'll try to make an example that really involves an additional logical step: *The softer B speaks, the less A hears, and the louder A speaks (to try to encourage B to be more audible)!  But since B is the shy type, the louder A speaks, the softer B speaks, and around we go again."

Answer (score 2):

Your first sentence is absolutely fine, and I like it without the conjunctions -- it feels more tiring for some reason.  The basic "the **_ the _**" construction is explained [here](http://www.englishgrammar.org/thethe-comparative-adjectives/).

Some might suggest that you have to set up a second comparison:  The more he walks, the less energy he has; the less energy he has, the more tired he gets.

But in the second part of the sentence, the two parts are basically saying the same thing.  I don't see why you can't add "the more tired he gets" to the first sentence, just for emphasis, but someone  else may come up with a reason why that doesn't work.